# Shell download script

Tags: mysql, shell, file, download, wget

I should write a sh script which downloads a file (around 100MB - 100GB) and writes the progress(percentage, download speed, remaining time) every 10 seconds in a mysql database.
Can someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not a code writing service. We prefer if you show us what you tried and we'll see if we can help you out. So, what have you tried? And why does it have to go into MySQL? Seems a bit of overkill.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've tried Wget and it downloads my file but now how can I get the status? Mysql isn't a must. Log to file is also okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` has the `--progress` option, but it's intended for humans who are watching the progress. `curl` also has a progress meter, but again, it's for humans.

You can send the progress info to a logfile with `wget -o`, and parse that.

```
--2017-03-01 13:13:21--  http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip
Resolving download.thinkbroadband.com (download.thinkbroadband.com)... 80.249.99.148
Connecting to download.thinkbroadband.com (download.thinkbroadband.com)|80.249.99.148|:80... connect
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1073741824 (1.0G) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘1GB.zip’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  150K 1h56m
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  308K 86m34s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 2.31M 60m10s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  348K 57m41s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 3.34M 47m10s
```

You'll have to write a program to parse that.

It's simpler and more flexible to write a little program using an HTTP client library which provides a progress callback. Here's an example in Perl using HTTP::Tiny.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use HTTP::Tiny;

my $url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip";

# A tiny HTTP client.
my $http = HTTP::Tiny->new;

# Track how many bytes have been received.
my $completed = 0;
$http->request("GET", $url, {
    # Add a callback when the next data hunk is received.
    data_callback => sub {
        # The data hunk, and info about the request.
        my($chunk, $response) = @_;

        # Add to the total received.
        $completed += length $chunk;

        # Get the total length (this won't always be available)
        my $length = $response->{'headers'}{'content-length'} || '?';

        # Calculate the percent received.
        my $percent = $completed / $length * 100;

        # Print it, making sure not to print too many decimal places.
        printf "%d of %d - %.2f%%\n", $completed, $length, $percent;

        return;
    }
});
```

Most languages have something similar. Now you can do whatever you like to record progress.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the great answer! I think I'll use the second method. Now my last question is can I start the perl script from php?